# One of the nextflow processes won't run/finish consistently

Tags: nextflow

I have a nextflow pipeline with four processes, the last process 'INTERSECT' is behaving odd, sometimes it just doesn't do anything but doesn't give any error either.
Example below:

```
nextflow run test_v3.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.6
Launching `test_v3.nf` [backstabbing_lumiere] DSL2 - revision: bb41e3dd9a
executor >  local (11)
[61/6edec1] process > GIMME_SCAN (3)    [100%] 5 of 5 ✔
[48/bfb62c] process > EXTRACT_GIMME (5) [100%] 5 of 5 ✔
[23/b911e5] process > EXTRACT_NR_MOTIFS [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
[-        ] process > INTERSECT
```

If I -resume, it executes fine and outputs expected results.

```
nextflow run test_v3.nf  -resume
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.6
Launching `test_v3.nf` [festering_bardeen] DSL2 - revision: bb41e3dd9a
executor >  local (5)
[52/17a139] process > GIMME_SCAN (2)    [100%] 5 of 5, cached: 5 ✔
[46/61caed] process > EXTRACT_GIMME (1) [100%] 5 of 5, cached: 5 ✔
[23/b911e5] process > EXTRACT_NR_MOTIFS [100%] 1 of 1, cached: 1 ✔
[d8/42ae7a] process > INTERSECT (Ss4)   [100%] 5 of 5 ✔
```

I am new to nextflow and can't figure out how to set dependencies in execution. Could someone please help me with this.

my nextflow pipeline is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.input = "beds/*.bed"
params.pfm = file("nonredundant.motifs.pfm")
params.nr_count = file("motif.nr.count.txt")

params.gimme_scan_bed_files = './results/gimme_extract/*/*.bed'
params.coord_bed_files = './results/motifs_nr_coord/*.bed'
params.outdir = './results/intersect'

process GIMME_SCAN {
    publishDir 'results/gimme_scan', mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

    input:
    path BED
    path PFM
    
    output:
    file ("${BED}_gimme.scan.bed")

    script:
    """
    gimme scan $BED -g Ssal_v3.1 -p $PFM -f 0.05 -b > ${BED}_gimme.scan.bed
    """
}


process EXTRACT_GIMME {
    publishDir 'results/gimme_extract', mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

    input:
    path gimme_scan_file
 
    output:
    path '*'

    script:
    """
    Rscript '$baseDir/gimmeScan_extract_motifs.R' $gimme_scan_file gimme_extract
    """
}

process EXTRACT_NR_MOTIFS {
    publishDir 'results/', mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

    input:
    path nr_count

    output:
    path '*'

    script:
    """
    Rscript '$baseDir/extract_motifs_maelstrom.R' $nr_count
    """
}


process INTERSECT {

    tag { scan_id }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(scan_id), path('bed_dir/*')
    path 'coord_dir/*'

    output:
    tuple val(scan_id), path("${scan_id}/*")

    shell:
    '''
    mkdir "!{scan_id}"
    for bed in bed_dir/*; do

        bedtools intersect \\
            -a "${bed}" \\
            -b "coord_dir/$(basename "${bed}")" \\
            -wa |
        sort \\
            -u \\
            > "!{scan_id}/$(basename "${bed}" '.bed')_intersected.bed"
    done
    '''
}

workflow {
    input_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.input)
    pfm_file = params.pfm
    nr_count_file = params.nr_count

    GIMME_SCAN(input_ch, pfm_file)
    EXTRACT_GIMME(GIMME_SCAN.out.flatten())
    EXTRACT_NR_MOTIFS(nr_count_file)
    
    Channel
        .fromFilePairs( params.gimme_scan_bed_files, size: -1) {
            it.parent.name.substring(it.parent.name.lastIndexOf('_') + 1)
        }
        .set { gimme_scan_bed_files }

    Channel
        .fromPath( params.coord_bed_files )
        .collect()
        .set { coord_bed_files }

    INTERSECT(gimme_scan_bed_files, coord_bed_files)
}
```

Thanks for your help.

ps: contents of .nextflow.log is as follows:

```
$ cat .nextflow.log
Apr-03 16:32:55.054 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cli.Launcher - $> nextflow run extract_motif_loc.nf
Apr-03 16:32:55.124 [main] INFO  nextflow.cli.CmdRun - N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.6
Apr-03 16:32:55.144 [main] DEBUG nextflow.plugin.PluginsFacade - Setting up plugin manager > mode=prod; embedded=false; plugins-dir=/home/pdewari/.nextflow/plugins; core-plugins: nf-amazon@1.11.3,nf-azure@0.14.2,nf-codecommit@0.1.2,nf-console@1.0.4,nf-ga4gh@1.0.4,nf-google@1.4.5,nf-tower@1.5.6,nf-wave@0.5.3
Apr-03 16:32:55.155 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.DefaultPluginStatusProvider - Enabled plugins: []
Apr-03 16:32:55.156 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.DefaultPluginStatusProvider - Disabled plugins: []
Apr-03 16:32:55.160 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.DefaultPluginManager - PF4J version 3.4.1 in 'deployment' mode
Apr-03 16:32:55.172 [main] INFO  org.pf4j.AbstractPluginManager - No plugins
Apr-03 16:32:55.239 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cli.CmdRun - Applied DSL=2 from script declararion
Apr-03 16:32:55.261 [main] INFO  nextflow.cli.CmdRun - Launching `extract_motif_loc.nf` [furious_wescoff] DSL2 - revision: 938a4809dd
Apr-03 16:32:55.261 [main] DEBUG nextflow.plugin.PluginsFacade - Plugins default=[]
Apr-03 16:32:55.262 [main] DEBUG nextflow.plugin.PluginsFacade - Plugins resolved requirement=[]
Apr-03 16:32:55.272 [main] DEBUG nextflow.secret.LocalSecretsProvider - Secrets store: /home/pdewari/.nextflow/secrets/store.json
Apr-03 16:32:55.279 [main] DEBUG nextflow.secret.SecretsLoader - Discovered secrets providers: [nextflow.secret.LocalSecretsProvider@6f3f0fae] - activable => nextflow.secret.LocalSecretsProvider@6f3f0fae
Apr-03 16:32:55.364 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session UUID: df0e66b3-cf2f-4b38-864f-084e5853d983
Apr-03 16:32:55.364 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Run name: furious_wescoff
Apr-03 16:32:55.364 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Executor pool size: 8
Apr-03 16:32:55.378 [main] DEBUG nextflow.util.ThreadPoolBuilder - Creating thread pool 'FileTransfer' minSize=10; maxSize=24; workQueue=LinkedBlockingQueue[10000]; allowCoreThreadTimeout=false
Apr-03 16:32:55.407 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cli.CmdRun - 
  Version: 22.10.6 build 5843
  Created: 23-01-2023 23:20 UTC (23:20 BST)
  System: Linux 5.14.0-1054-oem
  Runtime: Groovy 3.0.13 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.13+7-b1751.21
  Encoding: UTF-8 (UTF-8)
  Process: 2840906@MVM-EB-L20071 [127.0.1.1]
  CPUs: 8 - Mem: 15 GB (8.2 GB) - Swap: 2 GB (960.1 MB)
Apr-03 16:32:55.441 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Work-dir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work [ext2/ext3]
Apr-03 16:32:55.441 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Script base path does not exist or is not a directory: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/bin
Apr-03 16:32:55.451 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - Extension executors providers=[]
Apr-03 16:32:55.463 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Observer factory: DefaultObserverFactory
Apr-03 16:32:55.489 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cache.CacheFactory - Using Nextflow cache factory: nextflow.cache.DefaultCacheFactory
Apr-03 16:32:55.500 [main] DEBUG nextflow.util.CustomThreadPool - Creating default thread pool > poolSize: 9; maxThreads: 1000
Apr-03 16:32:55.589 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session start
Apr-03 16:32:56.659 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Launching execution
Apr-03 16:32:56.795 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - << taskConfig executor: null
Apr-03 16:32:56.795 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - >> processorType: 'local'
Apr-03 16:32:56.804 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.Executor - [warm up] executor > local
Apr-03 16:32:56.811 [main] DEBUG n.processor.LocalPollingMonitor - Creating local task monitor for executor 'local' > cpus=8; memory=15 GB; capacity=8; pollInterval=100ms; dumpInterval=5m
Apr-03 16:32:56.933 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - << taskConfig executor: null
Apr-03 16:32:56.933 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - >> processorType: 'local'
Apr-03 16:32:56.937 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - << taskConfig executor: null
Apr-03 16:32:56.938 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - >> processorType: 'local'
Apr-03 16:32:56.993 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - << taskConfig executor: null
Apr-03 16:32:56.993 [main] DEBUG nextflow.executor.ExecutorFactory - >> processorType: 'local'
Apr-03 16:32:57.002 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Workflow process names [dsl2]: EXTRACT_GIMME, GIMME_SCAN, EXTRACT_NR_MOTIFS, INTERSECT
Apr-03 16:32:57.003 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Igniting dataflow network (7)
Apr-03 16:32:57.009 [PathVisitor-1] DEBUG nextflow.file.PathVisitor - files for syntax: glob; folder: beds/; pattern: *.bed; options: [:]
Apr-03 16:32:57.009 [main] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Starting process > GIMME_SCAN
Apr-03 16:32:57.010 [main] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Starting process > EXTRACT_GIMME
Apr-03 16:32:57.011 [main] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Starting process > EXTRACT_NR_MOTIFS
Apr-03 16:32:57.013 [PathVisitor-2] DEBUG nextflow.file.PathVisitor - files for syntax: glob; folder: ./results/gimme_extract/; pattern: */*.bed; options: [:]
Apr-03 16:32:57.013 [main] DEBUG nextflow.processor.TaskProcessor - Starting process > INTERSECT
Apr-03 16:32:57.013 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Awaiting termination 
Apr-03 16:32:57.013 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await
Apr-03 16:32:57.014 [PathVisitor-3] DEBUG nextflow.file.PathVisitor - files for syntax: glob; folder: ./results/motifs_nr_coord/; pattern: *.bed; options: [:]
Apr-03 16:32:57.019 [PathVisitor-3] DEBUG nextflow.file.PathVisitor - No such file: ./results/motifs_nr_coord/ -- Skipping visit
Apr-03 16:32:57.020 [PathVisitor-2] DEBUG nextflow.file.PathVisitor - No such file: ./results/gimme_extract/ -- Skipping visit
Apr-03 16:32:57.217 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Apr-03 16:32:57.219 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [8c/e5a0ac] Submitted process > GIMME_SCAN (5)
Apr-03 16:32:57.228 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Apr-03 16:32:57.229 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [19/c27748] Submitted process > GIMME_SCAN (1)
Apr-03 16:32:57.235 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Apr-03 16:32:57.236 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [5d/28c5ab] Submitted process > EXTRACT_NR_MOTIFS
Apr-03 16:32:57.244 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Apr-03 16:32:57.245 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [1e/3343c1] Submitted process > GIMME_SCAN (4)
Apr-03 16:32:57.252 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Apr-03 16:32:57.253 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [d2/849345] Submitted process > GIMME_SCAN (3)
Apr-03 16:32:57.261 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Apr-03 16:32:57.276 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [0d/5513d1] Submitted process > GIMME_SCAN (2)
Apr-03 16:35:18.500 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 5; name: GIMME_SCAN (4); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -; workDir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work/1e/3343c128e22ab3b05d96efc9e221e8]
Apr-03 16:35:18.650 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Apr-03 16:35:18.727 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [8e/a8ba92] Submitted process > EXTRACT_GIMME (1)
Apr-03 16:35:18.963 [Task monitor] DEBUG nextflow.util.ThreadPoolBuilder - Creating thread pool 'PublishDir' minSize=10; maxSize=24; workQueue=LinkedBlockingQueue[10000]; allowCoreThreadTimeout=false
Apr-03 16:35:47.499 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 2; name: GIMME_SCAN (2); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -; workDir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work/0d/5513d184a8883c6a4b7c53955e9606]
Apr-03 16:35:47.514 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Apr-03 16:35:47.522 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [15/f4712f] Submitted process > EXTRACT_GIMME (2)
Apr-03 16:36:01.440 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 3; name: EXTRACT_NR_MOTIFS; status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -; workDir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work/5d/28c5abf48258d0e8b2063d3ddc258c]
Apr-03 16:36:06.195 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 6; name: GIMME_SCAN (5); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -; workDir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work/8c/e5a0acd7d95e67f0df1fd82d3e6e5b]
Apr-03 16:36:06.210 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Apr-03 16:36:06.211 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [70/35fd33] Submitted process > EXTRACT_GIMME (3)
Apr-03 16:36:09.921 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 1; name: GIMME_SCAN (1); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -; workDir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work/19/c277486903547af29fb04c06bf6f54]
Apr-03 16:36:09.950 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Apr-03 16:36:09.951 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [69/8092c2] Submitted process > EXTRACT_GIMME (4)
Apr-03 16:36:17.948 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 7; name: EXTRACT_GIMME (1); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -; workDir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work/8e/a8ba92563bf47fca01e65e84af3a61]
Apr-03 16:36:19.946 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 4; name: GIMME_SCAN (3); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -; workDir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work/d2/849345d841e15d00eb8cdca9e3ca71]
Apr-03 16:36:19.954 [Task submitter] DEBUG n.executor.local.LocalTaskHandler - Launch cmd line: /bin/bash -ue .command.run
Apr-03 16:36:19.954 [Task submitter] INFO  nextflow.Session - [f8/d5b8e7] Submitted process > EXTRACT_GIMME (5)
Apr-03 16:36:20.143 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 8; name: EXTRACT_GIMME (2); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -; workDir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work/15/f4712f5cf2134f66d468414cef6cb0]
Apr-03 16:36:28.895 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 9; name: EXTRACT_GIMME (3); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -; workDir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work/70/35fd33f651416f11d043e139520bb6]
Apr-03 16:36:32.813 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 10; name: EXTRACT_GIMME (4); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -; workDir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work/69/8092c20050d98b4871f2fc5c4be5c2]
Apr-03 16:36:41.082 [Task monitor] DEBUG n.processor.TaskPollingMonitor - Task completed > TaskHandler[id: 11; name: EXTRACT_GIMME (5); status: COMPLETED; exit: 0; error: -; workDir: /home/pdewari/Documents/2022/Final_analysis_Salmon/Salmon/chromHMM_2023/model_Ss_12_blacklist_filtered/act_enh_12states/Act_Enh_12states_JASPAR2022_vertebrates.out/test/gimme_scan/nextflow_pipe/work/f8/d5b8e75f4a2be2b4838e5aa43875a8]
Apr-03 16:36:41.086 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await > all processes finished
Apr-03 16:36:41.089 [main] DEBUG nextflow.Session - Session await > all barriers passed
Apr-03 16:36:41.116 [main] DEBUG nextflow.util.ThreadPoolManager - Thread pool 'PublishDir' shutdown completed (hard=false)
Apr-03 16:36:41.122 [main] DEBUG nextflow.trace.WorkflowStatsObserver - Workflow completed > WorkflowStats[succeededCount=11; failedCount=0; ignoredCount=0; cachedCount=0; pendingCount=0; submittedCount=0; runningCount=0; retriesCount=0; abortedCount=0; succeedDuration=20m 37s; failedDuration=0ms; cachedDuration=0ms;loadCpus=0; loadMemory=0; peakRunning=6; peakCpus=6; peakMemory=0; ]
Apr-03 16:36:41.164 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cache.CacheDB - Closing CacheDB done
Apr-03 16:36:41.171 [main] DEBUG nextflow.util.ThreadPoolManager - Thread pool 'FileTransfer' shutdown completed (hard=false)
Apr-03 16:36:41.172 [main] DEBUG nextflow.script.ScriptRunner - > Execution complete -- Goodbye
```

Comment: We need the `.nextflow.log` file to try to understand what's happening. It could be waiting for files to be staged in/out files or waiting for something similar before launching `INTERSECT`. The log will probably show this.

Comment: I have updated the question with contents of .nextflow.log file.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're trying to access some output files in the [publishDir](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#publishdir), but they do not exist until the (first) run is complete. The solution is to make sure to access the output files using one or more channels *only*:

> Files are copied into the specified directory in an asynchronous
> manner, so they may not be immediately available in the published
> directory at the end of the process execution. For this reason,
> downstream processes should not try to access output files through the
> publish directory, but through channels.

It's not clear to me what the outputs of your Rscripts are (using `output: path('*')` doesn't tell us much), but if I have understood correctly, the following *might* work for you. It should at least get you started:

```
arams.input_beds = "./beds/*.bed"
params.pfm = "nonredundant.motifs.pfm"
params.nr_count = "motif.nr.count.txt"

params.outdir = './results'
```

```
process GIMME_SCAN {

    tag { sample }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/gimme_scan", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(bed)
    path pfm
    
    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${bed.baseName}_gimme.scan.bed")

    """
    gimme scan \\
        -g Ssal_v3.1 \\
        -p "${pfm}" \\
        -f 0.05 \\
        -b \\
        "${bed}" \\
        > "${bed.baseName}_gimme.scan.bed"
    """
}
```

```
process EXTRACT_GIMME {

    tag { sample }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/gimme_extract", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path(gimme_scan_file)
 
    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${sample}/*.bed")

    """
    gimmeScan_extract_motifs.R \\
        "${gimme_scan_file}" \\
        "${sample}"
    """
}
```

```
process EXTRACT_NR_MOTIFS {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/extract_nr_motifs", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path nr_count

    output:
    path '*.bed'

    """
    extract_motifs_maelstrom.R "${nr_count}"
    """
}
```

```
process INTERSECT {

    tag { sample }

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/intersect", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(sample), path('bed_dir/*')
    path 'coord_dir/*'

    output:
    tuple val(sample), path("${sample}/*")

    shell:
    '''
    mkdir "!{sample}"
    for bed in bed_dir/*; do

        bedtools intersect \\
            -a "${bed}" \\
            -b "coord_dir/$(basename "${bed}")" \\
            -wa |
        sort \\
            -u \\
            > "!{sample}/$(basename "${bed}" '.bed')_intersected.bed"
    done
    '''
}
```

```
workflow {

    input_beds = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.input_beds, size: 1 )
    pfm_file = file( params.pfm )
    nr_count_file = file( params.nr_count )

    EXTRACT_NR_MOTIFS( nr_count_file )

    GIMME_SCAN( input_beds, pfm_file )
    EXTRACT_GIMME( GIMME_SCAN.out )
    
    INTERSECT( EXTRACT_GIMME.out, EXTRACT_NR_MOTIFS.out )
}
```

Note that you can move your Rscripts into a a folder called 'bin' in the root directory of your project repository. Nextflow automatically adds this folder to the `PATH` in the execution environment<sup>[1](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/sharing.html#third-party-scripts)</sup>. If they're not already executable, you can make them executable using `chmod +x your_script.R` for example.